# Why don't my integration tests run while invoking the "mvn test" command?

Tags: maven, integration-testing, maven-failsafe-plugin

Currently my integration tests only run when I run `mvn install`. I would like to have them run when I do `mvn test`.

My `<pluginManagement>` section contains:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    ...
</pluginManagement>
```

How can I make the integration tests run when I give only the goal `test`?

Comment: Why? They are invoked in the `integration-test` phase and you can call `mvn verify` if you want.

Comment: (Fixed the title of this question). I want to know if this is possible. And how.

Comment: My question stays the same: why do you want your ITs to be invoked when running `mvn test`? They are normally invoked in the `integration-test` phase and you normally want to invoke `mvn verify` to run the ITs so that things in the `post-integration-test` phase are run.

Comment: one should make a habit of running `mvn verify` instead of `maven test` or `mvn package` if one wants to avoid install but still execute local tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is special phases 
for running integration tests:

- pre-integration-test - configure test environment.
- integration-test - run the tests.
- post-integration-test - stop integration test environment.
- verify - check the results.

They run sequentially, so if you call

```
mvn integration-test
```

and it fails, post-integration-test phase won't be invoked.

But if you want to call it within the "test" phase, just move the tests to the appropriate phase:

```
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                <phase>test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score -1):

Unlike unit tests, integration tests are not executed by default.
You will have to create a separate profile in your pom.xml with the integration tests related configuration and use this profile when specifying the goal. 
For eg:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>integration-test</id>     // name of the profile
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-integration-test-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/integration/java</source>     // location where your code related to integration tests are present
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
                            <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/integration/resources</directory>       // location where resources related to your integration tests are present
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
                        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now in order to run your integration tests, you can issue the maven command as follows:

mvn clean install -P integration-test

Here -P option is used to specify the profile and integration-test is the profile name that we created earlier in the pom.xml

Comment: It is a good trick to profile out heavy integration tests, but if they are quick I would stick to running them unconditional before the verify phase.